# Is there a disease where cats arch their backs and run weird, sideways?

Tags: cats, health, diseases

I think I saw this behavior in a funny cat youtube video where the cat arches its back and runs sideways in a weird way, and in the youtube comments it was explained that this wasn't funny - it was a disease.

Well, maybe this is nothing, but I have a 2-3 month old kitten that did what looked like the same thing. It was very weird and didn't look calculated.

It arched its back and ran sideways into the wall and furniture a few times, for no reason.

Is that a symptom of some disease?

I'll be taking the kitten to the vet today, was just asking for perhaps a quick answer.

Comment: It sounds like a startle reflex (and normal, especially for a kitten). Do you know what disease they claimed it was, or have the link for the video so we can view the behavior?

Comment: I would be curious to see the video as well, but I'm with Zaralynda, it sounds like normal reflex for a kitten. I've seen them do very similar during play hunting and it looks really awkward (and often funny).

Comment: it's a normal reflex for a cat, too- the idea is to look big to a competitor/predator.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not a disease.  Cats run like this when they are frightened, playing, or just trying to appear bigger than themselves.  There are likely more reasons too.  It's a reflexive action that can give you insight into their mood.

I suppose it's possible a cat can have a 'disease' similar to human Tourettes (a neurological disorder), but remember that cats use their body to communicate, and if they use communication it's more likely that you should listen to your cat and his / her needs than speculative youtube videos.